# Enhanced Ecommerce GA

Tags: php, jquery, magento, google-analytics, universal-analytics

I am trying to implement EC GA code into my site created with Magento.

As you can see I added my analytics JS into `header.phtml` for every page.

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-xxxxxxx-1', 'auto');
ga('require', 'linkid', 'linkid.js');
ga('require', 'ec');
ga('send', 'pageview');
</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

Then I want to continue adding specific EC code whenever user add to cart. So I add this in my jQuery add to cart event on individual product page (`view.phtml`).

```
ga('ec:addProduct', {
  'id': 'P12345',
  'name': 'Some Shirt',
  'category': 'Apparel',
  'brand': 'Google',
  'variant': 'White'
});

ga('ec:setAction', 'detail');
ga('send', 'event')
```

My question is, separating the code like this is correct? Or do I need to add the create tracker code to my `view.phtml` as well?

Answer (score 0):

the code on header.phtml should be called in every page, this is correct.

But the Enhanced Ecommerce code that add products to the cart or send transactions for example, must be called before sending the pageview, not after it!

Also, you don't need is this case the line

```
ga('send', 'event')
```

Because you are not sending an event with the category and action at least. This line can be used in a click of button for instance.

Hope I've helped you.

Regards, 
Vítor Capretz

Comment: Hi Vitor, so what u mean is I should remove the ga('send', 'pageview') from header and replace it with ga('send', 'event') ? or just keep in header as it and add pageview send to view.phtml?

Comment: The ga('send', 'event') line doesn't even work without the category and action. What u should do is to put the content of view.phtml before the pageview on header.

Comment: I see but the problem is I can't move the add to cart js code to header and some more I need server variables from view.phtml.. thats why I'm trying to do separately ..

Comment: I just had an idea about adding ga('send', 'pageview') in the footer so it will only send once and it will be after everything else declare in header and view.. but not sure it will work though haha.. thanks for helping me out ...